# Javascript: Translation animation error

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a space invider in javascript:

I have a function that get the Spaceship position: *getstylevaiss* and it return it back ( left-margin ), so that I could position the missil with this function:

```
function tir(event){
    var actusizevaiss= getstylevaiss();
    var missile=document.getElementById("missile");
    if (event.which==38)
    {
        missile.style.marginLeft=actusizevaiss+"px";
        missile.style.bottom= "100px";
        missile.style.display="block"; // it was "none" before
        missile.style.position="absolute";
        while (parseInt(missile.style.bottom)<800) // while we are into the container
        {
        var animation = setInterval(tirer(),6000);
        }
          clearInterval(animation); 
    }
}

function getstylevaiss (){
    var vaiss= document.getElementById("vaisseau");
    var sizevaiss= vaiss.currentStyle ||window.getComputedStyle(vaiss);
    var actusizevaiss=parseInt(sizevaiss.marginLeft);
    return actusizevaiss;
}
```

Here's the function of translation from bottom to top :

```
function tirer(){
        var missile=document.getElementById("missile");
        var currt= missile.currentStyle ||window.getComputedStyle(missile);
        missile.style.bottom= parseInt(currt.bottom)+20+"px";
}
```

When I use *setInterval(tirer(),6000);* the missil goes to the top in just one time not fluid (and this is the problem ). But when I use *setInterval(tirer,6000);* Chrome get crached and I think that there is an infinit loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the more reliable requestanimationframe: It works a little differently, but it will fix you non-fluid experience.

Start here maybe? (Or Google)

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Comment: read the article I posted. The central problem is that the browser doesn't follow you interval if it is busy doing other things. So you will only get updates when the browser decides to execute your setinterval-function. Using animationframes gives you a sporting chance to code accordingly. :-)

Comment: I can't get use it in my function, if you could help me

Answer (score 0):

If this line: `missile.style.bottom= parseInt(currt.bottom)+20+"px";` , is what animates your object, and your issue is that it changes the position in one go instead of making it go smoothly, you need to use css transition here.

```
#missile
{
  transition: bottom 1s linear;
}
```

This is not the most reliable method if the distance that will be covered by the missile is different in different cases, because now the missile will always take 1s to complete the transition, whatever is the distance. Hope that helps.

And yes, you should use `requestAnimationFrame()`, which is much better than using `setInterval()`, but I think your current problem is not due to this.